# Gaussian region in $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

My question pertains to the paper ["A Simplified Proof of the Divergence Theorem"](http://docdro.id/E0I6BtA) by Djairo Guedes de Figueiredo.

The paper says:

> A *Gaussian region* is an open connected bounded set $V$ in $\mathbb R^n$, whose boundary $S$ is made up of two parts, $S_0$ and $S_1$, such that:
>
> 1) $S_0$ is a closed set of zero $(n-1)$-content;
>
> 2) for every point $x$ of $S_1$ there exists a neighborhood $N(x)$ such that $N(x) \cap S_1$ is a regular element of surface

What does it mean to say "$S_0$ is a closed set of zero $(n-1)$-content"? Does the author mean $S_0$ is a closed surface in $\mathbb R^{n-1}$?

Also, can a Gaussian region be thought as some arbitrary closed and bounded set in $\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: $(n-1)-$content means that looking for the perspective of null measure or content, you are taking rectangles on $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ and not on $\mathbb{R}^n$, it means that the measure is the measure on the subspace.

Closed's and bounded sets are compacts on $\mathbb{R}^n$, you can not confuse boundary of a set with boundary of a surface, for example...

Comment: So you are saying $S_0$ has zero measure (same thing as null measure?) on $\mathbb R^{n-1}$? I only I understand so far (hopefully) that $S=S_0 \cup S_1$ is a surface of positive measure in $\mathbb R^{n-1}$ and of zero measure in $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: And yes, I understand that boundary of set is not a boundary of a surface ... the surface itself is the boundary of the Gaussian region, right?

Comment: yes for both! null content means that you can cover by a finite quantity of rectangles, indeed you need some specie of compactness to conclude that them are the same thing. But yes, he is saying that $S_0$ has zero measure on $R^{n-1}.$ The question is that $S_0$ is closed and bounded, then compact, and then null measure is the same as null content.